# Code execution from Button without ActionListener

Tags: java, button, awt

So i have a button in my program (made with java.awt.Button) and I want to execute some code when i press the button. But i don't want to do this with an ActionListener. Is there a way to avoid the ActionListener?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: If nothing is listening then how will anything ever know that the button was pressed?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to listen for an action without using the very thing designed to do this in the first place?

Comment: Read this first. Understand what ActionListener is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Well...if you're hell bent against the **ActionListener** then perhaps use the **MouseListener** in conjunction with the **mouseClicked** event instead. :P

Comment: No - `ActionListener` takes into account various ways in which a butter can be triggered, including mouse, keyboard and programmatically - why would you not want to use the designed event notification mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `processActionEvent(ActionEvent e)` method, to execute the code.

```
Button btn = new Button("No Listener Button") {
    void processActionEvent(ActionEvent e) {
        // "some code" here
    }
};
```

Note that doing this will create a new anonymous class for every button you create this way, so it is not really a Good Idea™.  But it *will* do what you are asking; buyer beware.